# How does "filterpredicate" really work in a "MatTableDataSource"?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code, but I don't know how `filterpredicate` really works. I use it after declaring the datasource. But then in `this.dataSource.filteredData`, it doesn't print anything to me. It's as if the `filterpredicate` setting has no effect.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.miservicio.retornar2().subscribe( data => {

      this.autores = data;

      console.log(this.autores);

            
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ShirtId>(this.autores);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: ShirtId, filter: string) => {
        return data.nombre_autor == filter;
      
       };
      
    });  
    }

    filtrar(event: Event) {
      const filtro = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
      console.log("el filtro es este " + filtro);
      this.dataSource.filter = filtro.trim().toLowerCase();
      console.log(this.dataSource.filteredData);

       //this.dataSource.filter = filtro.trim().toLowerCase();
       
}
```